# Define random variables for a given correlation coefficient

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, correlation

Consider a sample space consisting of colors of balls in an urn, denoted by
$\Omega = \lbrace red, blue, green \rbrace$. Define a random vector $[X_{1}(w), X_{2}(w)]$, $w \in \Omega$ such that the random variables $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ 
have a correlation coefficient of 0.4. Note that $X_{1}, X_{2} \in \mathbb{R}$.

Using the brute force, it takes time to find $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ such that their correlation coefficient is 0.4. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: What was your result for $X_1$ and $X_2$ ?

Comment: I tried using brute force. But I didn't come across a solution. It was asked in my exam. I am just wondering whether there is an efficient way to do it in a short span of time.

Comment: One way to view this is that this sample space inherently is a source of multinomial trial, and a multinomial trial will have a negative correlation in between them. Therefore you may take $X_1$ and $X_2$ to be the indicator and negative of indicator of red and blue respectively. Simple calculation will let you obtain the correlation as $\displaystyle \frac {p_rp_b} {\sqrt{p_r(1-p_r)p_b(1-p_b)}} = 0.4$. There are many solutions to this, for simplicity take $p_r = 0.5$ to eliminate that, and solve for $\displaystyle p_b = \frac {4} {29}$.